# Cannot set map extent in ArcGIS JavaScript API 3.17

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

I have my map set to a custom projection SVY21/3414
This map service only supports Tiled and not Dynamic.
I manually convert the projection coordinates using proj4 and it works fine for my graphics.

I can get an extent object using esri/GraphicsUtils of the graphics on map which seems to be valid. However if I try to set map extent to this object I get error

```
undefined ""
```

in dojo.js

If I leave out the projection change and stick to 4236 it works fine.
I'm using version 3.17

Here's some sample code

```
 require(["esri/graphicsUtils"], function(graphicsUtils) {
    map.setExtent(graphicsUtils.graphicsExtent(arr));
  });
```

> Aforementioned code only works if I leave the projection change out.
>   Following code is how the graphics array is formed

```
var symbol = new PictureMarkerSymbol();
symbol.setUrl(thisicon);
var latlng = proj4(projection,[longitude,latitude]);
var point = new Point({x:latlng[0],y:latlng[1]});
// "projection" is the wkt string
var graphic = new Graphic(point, symbol, attr, template);
map.graphics.add(graphic);
```

Comment: can you share your code or sample?

Comment: updated with sample code

Comment: Are you sure the extent returned by GraphicsExtent is valid? If you've only added a single point to the graphics, aren't you then setting the map extent to a single point?

Comment: actually this is inside a loop. can confirm array is being populated perfectly and the extent object looks to be normal but i could be wrong.

Comment: the confusing thing is that if I just skip the "projection changing part", it works. arcgis has extremely useless error messages that convey nothing. Can you confirm that in theory this should work? I'll try to set up a fiddle.

Comment: new point which coordinate system 4326 or SVY21/3414
`var point = new Point({x:latlng[0],y:latlng[1]});`

Comment: the first point is always 3414 but x and y =0. All the rest are 4326 if spatialReference not specified and 3414 if explicitly specified. However same behavior when trying to zoom using extent

Answer (score 0):

found out the issue was to give "Point" a spatialReference. 
emredelioglu you were right to point into that direction. Even though the graphics have spatialReference set to correct one automatically. Unless I deliberately give it to Point, it wont work with graphics extent.